# Why does this delete test not delete my object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

This is what my spec looks like:

```
  it "should successfullly destroy that user record" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, :id => @user1.id
    }.to change{User.count}.by(-1)
  end
```

That calls this action in my `UsersController`

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully cancelled your account."
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

But when I run that spec, I get this:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected result to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit 1**

`@user1` is being initialized in a `before_each` call at the top of the `context` block that the `it` statement lives in. That looks like this:

```
context "when the inviter is being deleted and invited has not accepted invitation" do
  before :each do
    @user1 = create(:user, gender: 0)
    @user2 = create(:user)
    @member = create(:member, email: @user2.email, first_name: @user2.first_name, last_name: @user2.last_name, bio: @user2.bio, gender: @user2.gender)
    @membership = create(:membership, member: @member, family_tree: @user1.family_tree, inviter: @user1, relation: "sister")
    @connection = create(:connection, inviter_membership: @membership)
    login_user
  end
```

**Edit 2**

When I swap out the test with this, it works:

```
  it "should successfullly destroy that user record" do
    delete :destroy, id: @user1
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
    # expect {
    #   delete :destroy, id: @user1
    # }.to change(User,:count).by(-1)
  end
```

That test successfully passes.

```
Finished in 1.2 seconds (files took 6.08 seconds to load)
19 examples, 0 failures, 15 pending
```

**Edit 3**

For what it's worth, in my `UsersController` I am calling `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top. When I remove that, the test does seem to pass. So the question is, how do I get this to work with CanCanCan?

This is what my `ability.rb` looks like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end

    can :manage, FamilyTree, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, Comment, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, Node, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, Event, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, User, id: user.id

    can :read, Comment, user_id: user.id
    can :read, Event, user_id: user.id
  end
end
```

**Edit 4**

When I add a `raise` to my `destroy` action...nothing happens. So it does appear that my `destroy` action is indeed not being executed.

**Edit 5**

This is what my `login_user` method looks like:

```
module SpecAuthentication
  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in @user
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show where you're initializing `@user1`

Comment: @TylerFerraro I just updated the question with that info.

Comment: The test looks okay to me, perhaps try throwing another expect statement to verify if its redirecting to `:back` or to `:root_path`. The test could be failing because your user create statements are failing or not persisting.

Comment: @TylerFerraro - Yep...that works. I just updated the question with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `CanCanCan` gem you have to allow controller actions. You will need to add this to your `ability.rb` file.

`can :destroy, User`

This will allow anyone with that role to destroy a user object. You can add more specifics to fit your use case.

EDIT: Just saw the `:manage` documentation on the CanCanCan gem.

Your ability file currently allows users to manage themselves. Your `login_user` method is creating a user on the fly while your test is trying to destroy a separate user. You can either update your CanCan ability to let all users be destroyed or try destroying `current_user.id` assuming you have a `current_user` method. I would strongly suggest changing your `login_user` method to accept a user object so that you know which user is logged in and have access to that object.

EDIT:

As noted above, use a method to sign_in a specific user so that you can access it as an object. Replace the `login_user` call with `sign_in @user1` or a similar method that accepts a user object.

Comment: That actually raises another question, when I am running my specs, how can I figure out the `id` of the `current_user`?

Comment: Ah you're correct I was unfamiliar with `can :manage`. Can you show your `login_user` method?

Comment: Ahh interesting. Just updated my question with my `login_user` method.

Comment: Updating my answer above.

Comment: Ahh...this is perfect. The solution to this was simply to just delete the call to `login_user` and just do `sign_in @user1`. If you update your answer to suggest that I will accept it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Your `destroy` **action** is not being hit by the **spec**, check if there is some sort of a **before_action** preventing it from doing so.

I would do something like this:

```
  def destroy
    raise # The action was hit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully cancelled your account."
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

Comment: I just updated the question. When I modified the test to check the `redirect_to` path in the response, it seems to be going to the right place - which is the `root_path` which only happens if `@user.destroy` was successfully called in the controller. So it seems that it is actually hitting that `destroy` action, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the only `before_action` on my controller is the `load_and_authorize_resource` required for CanCanCan. Could it be an authorization issue? Not sure that's the case given the `redirect_to root_path` works from my previous comment.

Comment: If you put the `raise` statement at the top of your `destroy` action what do you get?

Comment: To go with what Marwen is getting at if you have `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` statement that redirects to `root_path` the above tests would look like they are working. Give the `raise` a try and we should get a clearer picture of whats going on.

Comment: Both of you guys seem to be correct. When I add `raise`, the test still fails and it doesn't actually raise an error. It just proceeds like normal. If you look at the question, I actually commented out the `load_and_authorize_resource` and the test passes. So now the question is, based on my `ability.rb` that I pasted in my question, how do I get this test to pass?